# How to make \left<\overrightarrow{b}\right> look good?

Tags: math-mode, arrows, brackets

I want a 'b' with an arrow on top, enclosed in angle brackets.

```
\left<\overrightarrow{b}\right>
```

gives angle brackets which are far too high.

```
<\overrightarrow{b}>
```

gives  far too much horizontal space between the brackets and the `\overrightarrow{b}`:

```
\left<\smash{\overrightarrow}\right>
```

makes that formula look good, but the upper end of the 'b' touches the line above.

So what I want is basically a `\smash` that only affects the brackets, but not e.g. line spacing. Is this possible?

Comment: There is also `\vec{b}` to make that arrow---perhaps you like it better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`<` and `>` are less than and greater than. If you use them where TeX expects delimiters (such as after `\left`, then you get angle brackets instead. I suspect what you want is just

```
\langle\overrightarrow{b}\rangle
```

which produces [image]

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
\left<\smash{\overrightarrow{b}}\vphantom{b}\right>\vphantom{\overrightarrow{b}}
```

This is probably going to give the same result as TH.'s answer, but it illustrates the technique to get what you want: a *b* with an arrow on top which is treated for the purpose of expanding delimiters as a plain *b*.

**Edit** You are right about the line spacing--the `\smash`ed `\overrightarrow{b}` will run over the line above.  I've added another `\vphantom` to stretch the line after the delimiter.

Comment: not quite. - As the arrow is not considered for line spacing, it can interfere with the above line. (at least it happened to me). Thanks however for explaining the \vphantom command.

Comment: @rainmaker: good point.  I fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

use `\big` instead of `\left`/ `\right`

```
$\big<\overrightarrow{b}\big>$
```

Comment: Gives the same result as @TH 's variant, except for the brackets being a bit bigger. Thanks.