# Reduce Spacing In $<a>$

Tags: math-mode, spacing

In math, one often needs to put a letter inside the symbols `<>`, e.g. to denote a cyclic group `<x>` generated by some element x. However, plain text displays the symbols `<` and `>` as an upside down exclamation point and an upside down question mark, respectively, while math type displays a large space like so:

```
< x >
```

Is there some way to reduce this spacing?

Comment: see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/the-trestle-problem-how-to-avoid-in-the-output and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13985/how-to-make-left-overrightarrowb-right-look-good (can any of those be considered duplicates)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's important to keep the same shape of `>` then make sure you're using the `amsmath` package because it gives you three types of negative space: thin, medium and thick. Per your question, negative spacing is the method to reduce spacing. This code shows your options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$<x>$\\
$\langle x \rangle$   \\
$< \, x \,>$\\
$< \negmedspace x \negmedspace >$\\
$< \negthickspace x \negthickspace >$\\
\end{document}
```

Personally, I like Jeff's solution or the solution with `negmedspace`.

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to mess with the spacing directly; frabjous's comment (under Jeff's answer) provides the best solution for this problem.

Comment: The solutions with explicit spacings (including the one with `\negmedspace`) are wrong. No discussion about it. Try with `$a=<\negmedspace x\negmedspace>$` and you'll clearly see why it's wrong when you compare it with `$a=\langle x\rangle$`: don't just look at the symbols, but also at the spacing.

Answer (score 19):

I swear I searched for a long time before posting my question....but right after asking, I found the solution.

For anyone else who might want to know, the solution is to use `\langle` in place of `<` and `\rangle` in place of `>`.

Comment: You can also do `$\left< x \right>$`, or if you really want `<` and `>` then `$\mathopen{<} x \mathclose{>}$`.

Comment: I would use `$\langle x\rangle$` instead of `$\left<x\right>$`, because `\left` and `\right` sometimes create delimiters of the wrong size and may also have other unwanted effects. I think `$\bigl\langle x\bigr\rangle$` and `$\bigl<x\bigr>$` come out exactly the same, though.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have is to include the following command in the beginning of the document:

\newcommand{\gen}[1]{\ensuremath{\langle #1\rangle}}

Remark: I have chosen the name of the command to be "\gen" by personal preference. This can be modified at will.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you explained in a bit more detail how your answer differs from the one by @DJP. If nothing else, it would be helpful if you mentioned that this approach requires use of the `amsmath` package.

Answer (score -1):

To keep the shape of the < and >, instead of squishing them horizontally: [https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/misc/hacks/langl_rangl.html](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Egbergman/misc/hacks/langl_rangl.html)

```
\usepackage{graphics}

\newcommand{\langl}{\begin{picture}(4.5,7)
\put(1.1,2.5){\rotatebox{60}{\line(1,0){5.5}}}
\put(1.1,2.5){\rotatebox{300}{\line(1,0){5.5}}}
\end{picture}}
\newcommand{\rangl}{\begin{picture}(4.5,7)
\put(.9,2.5){\rotatebox{120}{\line(1,0){5.5}}}
\put(.9,2.5){\rotatebox{240}{\line(1,0){5.5}}}
\end{picture}}

\newcommand{\lang}{\begin{picture}(5,7)
\put(1.1,2.5){\rotatebox{45}{\line(1,0){6.0}}}
\put(1.1,2.5){\rotatebox{315}{\line(1,0){6.0}}}
\end{picture}}
\newcommand{\rang}{\begin{picture}(5,7)
\put(.1,2.5){\rotatebox{135}{\line(1,0){6.0}}}
\put(.1,2.5){\rotatebox{225}{\line(1,0){6.0}}}
\end{picture}} 

%\langl \rangl produces 120 degree angle brackets
%\lang \rang produces 90 degree angle brackets
```